# Requisicao ajax - parametro de consulta

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

em uma pagina tenho esse campo preenchido com o valor "SP"

```
<input id="campo" value="SP">
```

No php tenho parametro

```
<?php
echo $_POST['estado'];
?>
```

para processar esse campo via ajax eu utilizaria

```
var valor=$('#campo').val();
```

na requisicação ajax,

```
data: {estado: valor},
```

o que eu quero é passar esse parametro 'estado' tambem dentro de uma variavel

```
var string="estado";
```

de modo que, na requisicão ajax fique assim:

```
data: {string : valor},
```

meu codigo

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var string="estado";
    var valor=$("#campo").val();
    ajsjax(string,valor);

    });
    </script>

function ajsjax(string,valor){
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html",
    url: "postos/cadastro_pegar_items.php", 
    data: {string : valor} , //as informações nao chegam aqui da forma correta
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }});
}
```

Comment: você quer que o `data` seja dinâmico?

Comment: Da uma olhada na minha resposta.

Comment: Esse link é bloqueado aqui na empresa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com a notação de JSON não dá para atribuir o nome da chave dinamicamente, o que você pode fazer é

```
function ajsjax(string,valor) {
    let data = {};
    data[string] = valor;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        url: "postos/cadastro_pegar_items.php", 
        data: data,
        success: function(resposta) {
            alert(resposta);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Melhor você editar sua pergunta, não estou entendendo nada do que você está dizendo. Sem contar que você nem tinha mencionado PHP.

Answer (score 0):

```
var valor_1 = "estado";
var valor_2 = "SP";

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      ajsjax(valor_1, valor_2);
    });
</script>

function ajsjax(valor_1, valor_2){
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html",
    url: "postos/cadastro_pegar_items.php", 
    data: {string : valor_2},
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode passar um objeto diretamente na sua `function`, por exemplo:

```
function ajsjax(campoParametro, valor) {
        var dados = {};
        dados[campoParametro]=valor;

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        url: "postos/cadastro_pegar_items.php", 
        data: dados,
        success: function(resposta) {
            alert(resposta);
        }
    });
}
```

Aí você pode chamar a `function` da seguinte maneira:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var campoParametro = "estado";
        var valor = $("#campo").val();

        ajsjax(campoParametro, valor);

    });
</script>
```

Pelo que entendi você quer que a `function ajsjax` seja dinâmica, caso queira passar outro valor em outra página é só criar o objeto com a propriedade com outro nome.

Comment: acesse www.meuposto.ml/2.html